# How to customize items of picker in Xamarin.forms as there is no ItemTemplate

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How we can customize items of Picker in Xamarin.Forms. I am not able to find ItemTemplate property in Picker.

If you are going to answer it like 'Use ListView',  then please mention how can 
we make selection in ListView same as Picker.Because selection  in Picker and ListView is completely different.

Any help is apprenticed.

For Example I want to display Picker like that...

[image]

Comment: Can you illustrate what you are looking for?

Comment: @EvZ I have attached sample image.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible. I think you can create a Popup with a ListView, where you have a ViewCell with all controls you need.

Try this Plugin https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: As I already mention in question that selection of item in ListView is completely different than in Picker. How we can achieve that with ListView? Is there any nuget package that I can use?

Comment: we have the same question [here.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85133/how-to-display-a-popup-control-and-add-listview-control-in-it) and this can useful for you. [Plugin](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)